# What is the networkid and chain id of truffle cli?

Tags: truffle, transactions, ethereumjs, raw-transaction, ethereumjs-tx

I am using truffle console to deploy contracts and using Nodejs/web3js to interact with it.  I wanted to use `ethereumjs-tx` for signing transactions, [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/HEAD/examples/custom-chain-tx.ts) is the reference link. I am not sure how can I find the **chain id** and **network id** of the local blockchain for which I need to create rawtransaction. i.e

```
const customCommon = Common.forCustomChain(
  'randomchainNmae',
  {
    name: 'my-network',
    networkId: ???,
    chainId: ???,
  },
  'petersburg',
)
```

Comment: `networkId` and `chainId` are the same thing AFAIK. And it's not on Truffle side, but on Ganache side (or whatever you're using as a blockchain provider). On Truffle side you can filter specific network IDs via the Truffle configuration file (truffle.js or truffle-config.js). But the configuration of the actual ID is on the provider side. For example, if you ARE using Ganache, then you can use `-i` or `--networkId` in order to specify the network id that ganache-cli will use to identify itself (see [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli)).

Comment: You can probably also obtain it programmatically from the `web3` instance which you're initializing in your script.

Comment: With web3 v1.0 the following works `web3.eth.net.getId()`.

Comment: no, `networkId` and `chainId` are NOT the same, and the purpose of `chainId` is to resist transaction replay attacks.  So this distinction is actually super-important but little-understood.  e.g. see https://medium.com/@pedrouid/chainid-vs-networkid-how-do-they-differ-on-ethereum-eec2ed41635b

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get both using the web3 instance of web3.js:

```
const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
const chainId = await web3.eth.getChainId();
```

Comment: You can just write these down to your truffle cli like "await web3.eth.getChainId()" and you will get your chain ID.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the title directly, the `chain_id` of `ganache` is 0x539 (or 1337).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know `network_id` then you can use the following network.
Check your `truffle.js`

```
   development: {
          host: '127.0.0.1',
          port: 8545,
          network_id: "*",
          from: "", // default address to use for any transaction Truffle makes 
        }
```